# There were a king with a large jaw... or There was?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

I am reading the novel 'A tale of two cities'. In the novel, the sentence goes like this: *There were a king with a large jaw and a queen with a plain face*.
My question is why *there were* is used here. Shouldn't it be *there was*? Thank you.

Comment: There were two of them: a king and a queen.

Comment: @WeatherVane Initially I thought the same. But this post confused me: https://www.englishforums.com/English/ThereWereOrWas/dwxpl/post.htm

Comment: The page you linked says that either form is acceptable.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes. In this link, they have used both. But my confusion is normally we use 'were' with plural and 'was' with singular

Comment: Dickens wrote the book in 1859 and today it seems strange. But there is a plural as I mentioned: There were two monarchs ruling in England. The king had a large jaw and the queen had a plain face. There was a king with a large jaw and [there was] a queen with a plain face.

Comment: Barrie England gives the definitive answer, properly referenced, at [There is / There are – does the choice depend on the plurality of the first list-element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. It is difficult to learn spoken English this way. After learning too much grammar, I am getting more and more confused while speaking 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both forms are possible.  Here is why.

> There were [two people] (a king... and a queen...)

> There was a king ... and [there was] a queen ...

Either of these sentences could express the same idea.  The second has two coordinated noun phrases, to produce a plural noun phrase "a king... and a queen".  The second has two parallel coordinated clauses, each is singular, the second has its subject implied by the parallelism.

So both were and was are correct.  Nowadays I feel the second is more common, especially when each singular noun phrase is complex. But Dickens's form is correct, and may have been more common 150 years ago.

Comment: Both forms are possible because people regularly use both forms. The form 'There's two boys on the beach' is commonly used, with _There's_ filling in for the expected but unwieldy _There're_.